# Formatting a Integer in VB

Tags: vb.net

How can I format a integer, `5500000.00` to something like `5,50 Mil.`?

How do i convert it or format it?

Thank You.

Comment: _"Must i convert the integer to a sting?"_ Yes, because that is a string and not an `int`. Btw, why does your integer have decimal places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to convert it to a string to display it that way, but you don't have to convert it to a string to actually get the numeric number of millions.  For instance:

```
Dim total As Integer = 5500000
Dim millions As Decimal = total / 1000000
Dim formatted As String = String.Format("{0} Mil.", millions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You probably don't realize the difference between integer, and it's display (in this case probably decimal) value. `5500000` is string. If you convert it to integer, it is stored somewhere in memory as `00000000 01010011 11101100 01100000` (in bits).

The display value, `5500000`, `55.0 Mil` are both strings. Computer doesn't know that `5500000` is number - it can only parse the text to it's numerical representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim value As Integer = 5500000
Dim valueInMil As Single = (CType(value,Single) / 1000000)
```